# Using Windows laptop to access Mac mini

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, remote-access, mac-mini

Is there a way to access my (headless) Mac mini from my Windows laptop? Via WiFi networking preferred, but if needed I can bring along a hub to connect the 2 machines.

I'm looking either for a good remote desktop solution or a way to use the laptop display for my Mac mini (and plugging in a keyboard into the Mac).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enable VNC screen sharing on your Mac Mini and use any VNC viewer (such as [VNC Viewer](http://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/)) to remote in from Windows.

In OS X 10.7, the VNC setting can be found under System Preferences, Sharing, Screen Sharing.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is to configure the Mac mini to join the network (WiFi or LAN) using a real monitor otherwise the VNC cannot be configured.

Comment: @PhilippSchmid, i suggest it's not necessary to join the network using a real monitor-- rather,  it's necessary to configure VNC on the Mac using a real monitor. Connection to the network is not required for configuration.